# Python: replace values in a 2d array from another 1d array based on some conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

thanks in advance for your help! I would like to the do the following, but I am new to Python, kind of unsure what to do efficiently.

1. I have a 2d array, for example `A=[[1,1],[2,3]]`.
2. Each value in the above 2d array corresponds to the index in another 1d array, for example: `B=[0.1,0.2,0.8,0.9]`.
3. The end result should be like: `C=[[0.2,0.2],[0.8,0.9]]`. That means, `C[i,j]=B[index=A[i,j]]`.

The above is a simple example. But in practice, A can be a huge array, so I would really appreciate if there is any way to do this efficiently. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your post, you already almost got the answer. If you are really looking for a one line code, you can do this.

```
c = B[A]

c
Out[24]: 
array([[0.2, 0.2],
       [0.8, 0.9]])
```

The code above is for numpy array. On the other hand, if it is a list,
list comprehension would be required.

Answer (score 1):

First try planning the sequence from index of first list and the relation with the result list.

```
A = [[1,1],[2,3]]
B=[0.1,0.2,0.8,0.9]

C = [[B[i] for i in j] for j in A]

print(C)
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this without a loop in numpy?

Comment: Really thanks for your help! But I am wondering is there any way to vectorize such a loop? Thanks!

Comment: @QuVergil I edited my answer for a shorter. I hope that it's that you mean

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments on answer by @PAUL ANDY DE LA CRUZ YANAC, I see that you are trying to use `numpy` and avoid `for loop` but as far as my knowledge, you need to use a `for loop` at least once.

```py
import numpy as np

for x, y in np.ndindex(np.array(A).shape):
    A[x][y] = B[A[x][y]]
```

Note: This approach changes the original list `A`. But if you want to create a new list, look at the solution by @Paul Dlc.